# I need to pull data from another Firestore collection based on forEach data within a onSnapshot call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I go about this? I can't figure it out from anything else I can find on here.

#### Background

I have collections in the Firestore for `posts` and `users`. The information is going to be rendered out in to a Posts components displaying all of the existing posts on the dashboard.

###### Users Collection

`users` holds an `avatar` property which stores an image URL. The doc id for each user is just their username as these are unique.

###### Posts Collection

`posts` have an `author` property which is exactly the same as the `username`/`doc.id`

#### The Aim

When iterating through the `posts` I want to push them to an array and store their `id` and the rest of the `post` data. I also need to relate this to the `users` collection and with each iteration, find the `avatar` of the `user` that matches the `post author`.

#### Things I've already tried

I have tried using `async/await` within the `forEach` loop, using the `post.author` value to get the correct `user document` and pulling the `avatar`.

#### `Posts` component code

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { collection, onSnapshot /*doc, getDoc*/ } from "firebase/firestore"
import { db } from "lib/firebase"
import AllPostsSkeleton from "components/Skeletons/AllPostsSkeleton"
import Tags from "components/Tags"
import defaultAvatar from "assets/images/avatar_placeholder.png"

const Posts = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
      collection(db, "posts"),
      (docs) => {
        let postsArray = []

        docs.forEach((post) => {
          // const docRef = doc(db, "users", post.author)
          // const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef)

          postsArray.push({
            id: post.id,
            // avatar: docSnap.data().avatar,
            ...post.data(),
          })
        })

        setPosts(postsArray)
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      }
    )

    setLoading(false)

    return () => unsubscribe()
  }, [])

  if (loading) return <AllPostsSkeleton />

  if (!posts) return <div className="no-posts">No posts to show</div>

  const RenderPosts = () => {
    const sortedPosts = posts.sort((a, b) => {
      return new Date(b.date.seconds) - new Date(a.date.seconds)
    })

    return sortedPosts.map(
      ({ id, author, slug, content, tags, comment_count, avatar }) => (
        <article className="post-preview media" key={id}>
          <figure className="media-left">
            <p className="comment-avatar image is-96x96">
              <img src={avatar || defaultAvatar} alt={content.title} />
            </p>
          </figure>
          <div className="media-content">
            <div className="content">
              <header className="post-header">
                <h2 className="title is-3">
                  <Link to={`/user/${author}/posts/${slug}`}>
                    {content.title}
                  </Link>
                </h2>
                <div className="tags">
                  <Tags data={tags} />
                </div>
              </header>
              <p className="post-excerpt">{content.excerpt}</p>
              <footer className="post-footer">
                Posted by
                <Link to={`/user/${author}`} className="capitalise">
                  {author}
                </Link>
                | <Link to={`/user/${author}/posts/${slug}`}>View Post</Link>
              </footer>
              <div className="content">
                <Link to={`/user/${author}/posts/${slug}#comments`}>
                  Comments ({comment_count})
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      )
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className="posts-list">
      <RenderPosts />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Posts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with Promises, especially with the Firebase SDK, you will see the `Promise.all(docs.map((doc) => Promise<Result>))` being used often so that the Promises are correctly chained together.

Even if you chain the Promises properly, you introduce a new issue where if a snapshot is received while you are still processing the previous snapshot of documents, you will now have two sets of data fighting each other to call `setPosts`. To solve this, each time the snapshot listener fires again, you should "cancel" the Promise chain fired off by the previous execution of the listener.

```js
function getAvatarsForEachPost(postDocSnaps) {
  return Promise.all(
    postDocSnaps.map((postDocSnap) => {
      const postData = postDocSnap.data();

      const userDocRef = doc(db, "users", postData.author)
      const userDocSnap = await getDoc(userDocRef)

      return {
        id: postDocSnap.id,
        avatar: userDocSnap.get("avatar"),
        ...postData,
      };
    })
  )
}

useEffect(() => {
  let cancelPreviousPromiseChain = undefined;
  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
    collection(db, "posts"),
    (querySnapshot) => { // using docs here is a bad practice as this is a QuerySnapshot object, not an array of documents
      if (cancelPreviousPromiseChain) cancelPreviousPromiseChain(); // cancel previous run if possible

      let cancelled = false;
      cancelPreviousPromiseChain = () => cancelled = true;

      getAvatarsForEachPost(querySnapshot.docs)
        .then((postsArray) => {
          if (cancelled) return; // cancelled, do nothing.
          setLoading(false)
          setPosts(postsArray)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (cancelled) return; // cancelled, do nothing.
          setLoading(false)
          console.log(error)
        })
    },
    (error) => {
      if (cancelPreviousChain) cancelPreviousChain(); // now the listener has errored, cancel using any stale data
      setLoading(false)
      console.log(error)
    }
  )

  return () => {
    unsubscribe(); // detaches the listener
    if (cancelPreviousChain) cancelPreviousChain(); // prevents any outstanding Promise chains from calling setPosts/setLoading
  }
}, [])
```

Notes:

- `setLoading(false)` should only be called once you have data, not as soon as you attach the listener as in your original answer.
- Consider using `setError()` or similar so you can render a message for your user so they know something went wrong.
- You could let a child `<Post>` component handle fetching the avatar URL instead to simplify the above code.
- Consider making a `getUserAvatar(uid)` function that has an internal cached map of `uid‑>Promise<AvatarURL>` entries so that many calls for the same avatar don't make lots of requests to the database for the same information.

Comment: Oh man, what an incredible answer, thank you so much. So much information, I really appreciate it. I didn't even think about using a child Post component. I get a bit messy with my own projects as I have no idea what I'm going to do when I start, so I have no planned components and end up shoving everything in to one. I need to refactor before it becomes more of a mess.

Notes taken on board thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The issue you are facing is because you are running an await inside a forEach loop. For Each loop doesn't return anything so you cant run await inside it. Please change the forEach to Map your logic should be working fine.