# Query collection and get data from other collection using the first one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know similar questions have been asked here:
[I need to pull data from another Firestore collection based on forEach data within a onSnapshot call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70283276/i-need-to-pull-data-from-another-firestore-collection-based-on-foreach-data-with)
and here:
[Using getDoc().then() inside of a loop Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70226994/using-getdoc-then-inside-of-a-loop-firebase)
but I really cannot adapt it to my own issue. I actually also consulted ChatGPT, but apparently, it only knows firebase v8.x.x :/

I have a comment collection and I'm querying these for specific content (url). I can get the comments in the first step just fine. Each comment document has a field called "user_id", I want to use this user ID to get information about the user from the collection "userinfo" and push it to the comments array. From what I can understand, the promise I get in my attempt (see code below), indicates that I need to use await, but this is apparently tricky in for loops and inside useEffect.
My attempt is below:

```
  const [allCommments, setAllCommments] = useState([]);
  const commentRef = collection(db, "comments");
  const q = query(commentRef, where("content", "==", url));

  useEffect(() => {
    onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
      const tempComments = [];
      snapshot.forEach((snapDoc) => {
        tempComments.push(snapDoc); // this works fine, the next steps doesn't:
        const userSnap = getDoc(doc(db, "userinfo", snapDoc.data().user_id));
        // tempComments.push(userSnap.data().firstname).push(userSnap.data().lastname) // what I want
        // console.log(userSnap.data()) // this gives the error "userSnap.data() is not a function"
        // console.log(userSnap); // this only returns a promise
      });
      setAllCommments(tempComments);
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Firebase SDK version.  The main problem is that you can't use an async function call like `getDoc` inside a `forEach` loop. and expect it to complete before the loop ends.  You will need to restructure your code so that the call to `setAllComments` happens only after all the async document fetches are fully complete.

Comment: I know it doesn't have anything to do with the version, but the solutions I got from chatGPT wouldn't help me :-)

Comment: ChatGPT does not really understand how to program a computer, it turns out.